# Git p4 Unable to execute git-p4 on ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, perforce

I am trying to run 'git-p4' command and see the following error :

```
fatal: git was built without support for git-p4 (NO_PYTHON=1)
```

Can anyone help how to fix this ?

I am running on Ubuntu 14.X.

Comment: Paste the error message into a Google search box and you'll find a Stack Overflow answer with the solution.

Comment: I believe you are talking about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636289/git-p4-fatal-git-was-built-without-support-for-git-p4-no-python-1 I could not fix it. 

what I tried :